# WWI Equivalent of "Gotcha!"

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, history

I am looking for an equivalent of "Gotcha!", "Made it!" or other exclamatory phrases a World War One Airplane Pilot may use.

The specific name is Frank Luke, an airplane ace. He just got out after successfully destroying three German Balloons, and he's making the statement to himself or over the radio while flying away from the situation.

I would think in modern times someone could say

- "Gotcha!"
- "That was easy!"
- "They got destroyed, no doubts"
- etc...

I have done some research, but still don't have a clue about how someone back then would exclaim phrases such as these.

Comment: Watch the 4th Blackadder series show where he joins the airforce. Not only do you get a thousand of them, but they are all sexual innuendoes as well.

Comment: @Oldcat any examples you can give here?

Comment: If I remember correctly, WWI pilots were from the upper classes, I have a feeling they were officers and were well-educated. Therefore, I doubt an upper crust officer with an Etonian education would say *Gotcha!*. You would need to check this out. *Gotcha* (I would surmise) would have crossed the social class barriers by the time WWII arrived.

Comment: The first *written* record of [gotcha](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=gotcha) is from 1913. Etymonline doesn't offer much else I'm afraid. This doesn't mean that *gotcha* wasn't said ten years earlier, but my gut instinct tells me that it was considered then (and even today by some) to be non-standard English. I guess, whether you choose this expression or not depends on how important authenticity is to you. At the very least you have proof it "existed" before the advent of WWI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Gotcha!** is used in [this 1916 book](http://books.google.com/books?id=0P4Rzk2xJj8C&pg=PA134&dq=%22gotcha%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=461mVLGILoWMyAT0yIDYDg&ved=0CDMQ6wEwBDgU) in the sense you want, but not by an aeroplane pilot, sorry, airplane pilot. But I would assume the term could feasibly be used by an airplane pilot. [Another example](http://books.google.com/books?id=WLMqAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA558&dq=%22gotcha%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=trFmVJ2aAoqRyQScuIDYCA&ved=0CEQQ6wEwBzgU).

Note: You can search for phrases using Google Ngram, [like this one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Gotcha&year_start=1900&year_end=1920&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CGotcha%3B%2Cc0). You have to keep in mind that not all uses have the same meaning. *I gotcha* has a lot of examples of *I hear ya* or *I understand ya,* but I found the above examples for you.

You can do similar for other phrases.

Edit: you could do Ngrams for WW1 era terms, such as *fokker, fokkers* or *fritzie, boche* and then browse for books that look like they might have first hand description or dialogue.

Or go to [project gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/) and search for *Aeronautics* or *aeroplane* and browse what books come up.

Answer (score 1):

The best word or phrase to use would depend on the nationality and social standing of the pilot.

For an upper-class Englishman "Hurrah" or "By gosh, that was easy."

For an American, perhaps "Gotcha".

Comment: Perhaps a little too "hooray Henry" but your answer is more probable, see my comment beneath the OP's question. (You might need to do a little background research on WWI pilots/RAF)